# Where can I buy a 4 terminal P-Channel Enhancement MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I have a simulation working with a 4 terminal MOSFET. I'm looking for experimentally verifying my circuit but I cannot find the P-Channel Enhancement MOSFET with a separate body connection to order online. The body is not connected to source but it is tied to VDD in my case, hence I would need to access the body terminal of the MOSFET.

Also, I know that PSpice has the IC and component part numbers. I could not find a 4 terminal MOSFET in there as well.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The only place I have seen body connections run out (for both BJTs and MOSFETs) are matched pairs that are part of a line that contains complimentary matched pairs. Check out Advanced Linear Device's products on Mouser. https://www.mouser.ca/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/_/N-ax1sf?Keyword=advanced+linear+devices&FS=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ALD1107/ALD1117](https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/ALD1117.pdf) is a dual/quad matched P-channel MOSFET array with a separate body connection. I have used these in a teaching environment to mimic simple CMOS integrated circuits. We were also able to use a model for those transistors. The ALD1106/ALD1116 is the same thing, but a N-channel array.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I just used the ALD1107 model that is here https://web.sonoma.edu/engineering/resources/models/.

Is that the one that you are talking about as well?

Comment: You can probably find a few places that use the models formatted for various software packages. You can also download them directly from ALD: https://www.aldinc.com/view-pdf.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the p-channel transistors connected to pins 1, 2, 3 & 14 in the [CD4007UB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf?ts=1596495560955&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4007UB). They're cheap and readily available parts.

[image]

You'll need to bias the substrate (pin 7) below the source, drain and body.